How to Fix Cisco AnyConnect Error on Ubuntu 24.04: Missing WebKitGTK+ Libraries?
I recently upgraded my system to Ubuntu 24.04, and since then, the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client (version 4.10.06090) has stopped working. When I try to access my company's VPN, I get the following error message:
"You are missing the required libraries for the authentication method you requested."
We use Azure for authentication. Checking the system logs, I found the following error:
acvpnui[91602]: Function: launchBrowser File: ../../../vpn/WebHelper/Plugin/WebHelperPluginImpl.cpp Line: 774 The AnyConnect embedded web browser requires WebKitGTK+ 2.1x or higher. Please install WebKitGTK+ and its dependencies.
I have verified that WebKitGTK+ is installed on my system. Here is the output of dpkg -l | grep webkit:
ii  gir1.2-webkit2-4.1:amd64                                    2.44.2-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                    amd64        Web content engine library for GTK - GObject introspection data
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64                                   2.44.2-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                    amd64        Web content engine library for GTK
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev:amd64                                 2.44.2-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                    amd64        Web content engine library for GTK - development files
ii  libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64                                    2.44.2-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                    amd64        Web content engine library for GTK

Despite having the necessary libraries, the error persists. I've tried reinstalling both the Cisco AnyConnect client and the WebKitGTK+ libraries, but the issue remains unresolved.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can anyone suggest a solution to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Fixed it with 3 simple steps
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev


Thanks for this, it works for me.

I managed to resolve the error by following the instructions found on the Cisco community forums. Here is the link to the original discussion: Cisco Community Forum.
The solution involves adding additional repositories to obtain the necessary WebKitGTK+ libraries. Here are the steps I followed (The following is a textual reference from link 1.):

Open the sources list file with a text editor:

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

Add the following repositories to the file:

Types: deb
URIs: http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: jammy noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: jammy-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


Update the package list (you might encounter some errors, but you can
proceed):

sudo apt update

Install the required package:

sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37

Finally, remove the repositories you added earlier from the
ubuntu.sources file.

Following these steps resolved the issue for me, and the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client (version 4.10.06090)  is now working correctly. I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem!
